# Attempted to load class "Roles" from namespace AppBundle\Repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.7

I have my Roles in the db:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Roles:
 type:     entity
 table:     Roles
 repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\Roles
```

Empty class for testing purposes:

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use AppBundle\Entity\Roles;

class RolesRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
}
```

and simple use case in my Controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\Roles;
class ClientsController extends CommonController
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // [...]
        $role = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getRepository('AppBundle:Roles')
               ->findOneBy(array('role'=>'ROLE_CLIENT'));
        // [ ...]
    }
}
```

And when only I put "repositoryClass: \AppBundle\Repository\Roles" in my .orm.yml file, I'm got the error:

> Attempted to load class "Roles" from namespace "\AppBundle\Repository".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your repository class name is `AppBundle\Repository\RolesRepository`, so in your entity config, instead of:

```
 repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\Roles
```

is should be:

```
 repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\RolesRepository
```